# How can i fix VBA Copy and Past Formula Error

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to insert the formula below into the rest of the column using the following VBA code. It will change the nest cell down but then i get a "#NAME?" error on the rest of the cells. Help, what am i doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim LstRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")

Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("F6:F" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(F5=F4,”P=”&ROW(F7)/2,F5)"
.Range("F6:F" & Lastrow).Copy
.Range("F6:F" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `”P=”` should be `""P=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `R1C1` Notation. Much faster, easier to implement. In `R1C1` everything is relative to the cell where the formula is written.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim LstRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("F6:F" & Lastrow)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=R[-2]C,""P=""&R[1]/2,R[-1]C)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
"=IF(F5=F4,”P=”&ROW(F7)/2,F5)"
```

with:

```
"=IF(F5=F4,""P="" & ROW(F7)/2,F5)"
```

Note The use of the "wrong-flavor" double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner gave the solution in ist comment

here's a possible optimization of the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        With .Range("F6:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
            .Formula = "=IF(F5=F4,""P=""&ROW(F7)/2,F5)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```